# "begins to drive" or "begins driving"?

Tags: sentence-choice

1. He starts the car and begins to drive around the warehouse.
2. He starts the car and begins driving around the warehouse.

Does one of these sound better/more natural than the other to you native English speakers?

Comment: Sound much the same to me.

Comment: What happens next? There are tiny differences between the two, but only relevant if we know more context.

Comment: This is the last sentence in a scene, so we don't know what happens next until later.